# The fate of Thrain

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

From the extended scene in The Desolation of Smaug, does Sauron actually kill Thrain or do we not find out?

I know in the book he dies in the dungeons but are we to expect anything more from this scene?

Comment: We may have to wait for the extended edition of *BotFA* to get an answer to this

Comment: Are you asking if Sauron kills Thráin or just leaves him to die?

Comment: He even has a Wilhelm scream, of course he dies.

Answer (score 3):

The Director's Commentary (a conversation between Director Peter Jackson and Lead Scriptwriter [Philippa Boyens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippa_Boyens)) explicitly confirms his death. The method isn't exactly clear but I think we can be reasonably certain that it wasn't a pleasant end.

Note, transcription mine (timecode : 02:11:12)

> **Philippa Boyens :** *...the death of Thrain...*
>
> **Peter Jackson :** *yeah...And of course we've disposed of poor old Thrain...he gets swallowed...swallowed by this black blob...*
>
> **Philippa Boyens :** *He knows what's coming*
>
> **Peter Jackson :** *...not a good
>   way to go, a black blob swallowing you seems like a pretty nasty way
>   to go...*